# Percorrer todas chaves de um json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Quero percorrer todas chaves de um json para que eu consiga obter todos os seus valores. Ex:

```
{
  "logistics_provider": "{{lp_name}}",
  "shipper": "{{co_common_name}}",
  "invoice_key": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "invoice_series": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "volume_number": "1",
   "events": [
  {
        "event_date": "{{ae_date}}",
        "original_code": "{{ae_code_event}}",
        "original_message": "{{ae_comment}}"
  }]
}
```

Portanto quero os valores `{{lp_name}}`, `{{co_common_name}}` etc ...

Comment: Você quer até dentro desses que são arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode percorrer o objeto com o `for...in` e verificar qual o tipo de propriedade:

```js
var objeto =  {
  "logistics_provider": "{{lp_name}}",
  "shipper": "{{co_common_name}}",
  "invoice_key": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "invoice_series": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "volume_number": "1",
    "events": [
  {
        "event_date": "{{ae_date}}",
        "original_code": "{{ae_code_event}}",
        "original_message": "{{ae_comment}}"
  }]
};

var resultado = [];

function percorrer(obj) {
  for (var propriedade in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propriedade)) {
      if (typeof obj[propriedade] == "object") {
        percorrer(obj[propriedade]);
      } else {
        resultado.push(obj[propriedade]);
      }
    }
  }
}

percorrer(objeto);
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultado));
```

No `ES6` você pode utilizar o `reduce` e a `Sintaxe de espalhamento`:

```js
const extrair = (origem) => {
  // Se for um array realiza a extração de seus itens
  if (Array.isArray(origem)) {
    return origem.reduce((acumulador, item) => [...acumulador, ...extrair(item)], []);
  }

  // Se for um objeto, verifica se algum dos valores é um array para realizar a extração
  return Object.values(origem).reduce((acumulador, item) => (
    [...acumulador, ...(Array.isArray(item) ? extrair(item) : [item])]
  ), []);
};

// Teste da função
const objeto =  {
  "logistics_provider": "{{lp_name}}",
  "shipper": "{{co_common_name}}",
  "invoice_key": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "invoice_series": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "volume_number": "1",
    "events": [
  {
        "event_date": "{{ae_date}}",
        "original_code": "{{ae_code_event}}",
        "original_message": "{{ae_comment}}"
  }]
};

console.log(extrair(objeto));
```

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

---

> [**Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
>
> **Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)** permite um objeto iterável tal como uma expressão de array ou uma string ser expandida onde zero ou mais argumentos (para chamadas de funções) ou elementos (para arrays literais) são esperados, ou um objeto ser expandido onde zero ou mais pares propriedade:valor (para objetos literais) são esperados.
>
> ```
> function sum(x, y, z) {
>   return x + y + z;
> }
>
> const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
>
> console.log(sum(...numbers));
> // expected output: 6
>
> console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));
> // expected output: 6
> ```

---

**Referência:** [Recursively looping through an object to build a property list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list).

Answer (score 3):

Levando em conta que a estrutura do JSON é essa, você pode usar [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para ler as chaves e valores dos dois níveis:

```js
var obj = {
  "logistics_provider": "{{lp_name}}",
  "shipper": "{{co_common_name}}",
  "invoice_key": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "invoice_series": "{{ae_identifier}}",
  "volume_number": "1",
  "events": [{
    "event_date": "{{ae_date}}",
    "original_code": "{{ae_code_event}}",
    "original_message": "{{ae_comment}}"
  }]
};

for (key in obj) { // obtém as chaves do objeto
  // se o valor for diferente de objeto (caso events)
  if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') 
    console.log("Chave: " + key + " - Valor: " + obj[key]);
  else
    // se o valor for um array de objetos, é iterado o array
    // e as chaves de cada objeto
    obj[key].forEach(function(item) {
      for (key2 in item) {
        console.log("Chave: " + key2 + " - Valor: " + item[key2]);
      }
    });
}
```